Did God use an evil spirit in 1 Kings 22?

19 Micaiah continued, "Therefore hear the word of the LORD: I saw the LORD sitting on his throne with all the multitudes of heaven standing around him on his right and on his left. 20 And the LORD said, 'Who will entice Ahab into attacking Ramoth Gilead and going to his death there?' "One suggested this, and another that. 21 Finally, a spirit came forward, stood before the LORD and said, 'I will entice him.' 22 " 'By what means?' the LORD asked. " 'I will go out and be a deceiving spirit in the mouths of all his prophets,' he said. " 'You will succeed in enticing him,' said the LORD. 'Go and do it.' 23 "So now the LORD has put a deceiving spirit in the mouths of all these prophets of yours. The LORD has decreed disaster for you." [1Ki 22:19-23 NIV]

Can God use evil spirits to accomplish his purposes? From 1 Smauel 16, Job 2:3-6, Psalm 82, and the passage above we see that fallen entities have had access to the divine throne room. In Revelation 9 we see 4 unfriendly angels who "kill a third of mankind." [Rev 9:15 NIV]
Yet the holy angel declares, 5b "You are just in these judgments, O Holy One, you who are and who were; [Rev 16:5b NIV] Yes, God always is just.
